# how to set password in version 2 in snmp exporter

Tags: prometheus, snmp, exporter

I set the password on the Cisco switch with version 2 of the snmp, but I could not get data with the exporter snmp how to set just password in snmp exporter for version2

error

level=info ts=2020-12-27T11:37:06.875Z caller=collector.go:224 module=if_mib target=172.16.108.10 msg="Error scraping target" err="scrape canceled (possible timeout) getting target 172.16.108.10"

```
version: 2
    auth:
      community: public
      username: snmp
      security_level: noAuthNoPriv
      password: **********
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each module, a community process must be defined separately, each of which can be connected separately, and that version 2 does not have a password at all.